# How can I speedup this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is very slow and I'm looking for a way to optimize.

Any ideas?

```
select *, 
      (rating / (select max(rating) from products)) rk_rating, (reviews / 
      (select max(reviews) from products)) rk_reviews, 
      (if(label = "", 0, 1)) rk_label, 
      (1 - price / (select max(price) from products)) rk_price 
from `products` 
where (`locale` = 'it' or `locale` = '*') 
  and `id` in (select `product_id` 
               from `location_product` 
               where `location_product`.`location_id` in (select `id` 
                                                          from `locations` 
                                                          where `place_id` = 'ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI' or `city_place_id` = 'ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI')) 
order by (rk_rating * '2' + rk_reviews * '5' + rk_label * '0.5' + rk_price * '50') desc limit 21 offset
```

Comment: A very minor improvement (to readability if nothing else) is to generate your order by value in your first select: `select ..., (rk_rating * 2 + rk_label * 0.5 + rk_price * 50) rk_order from ..... order by rk_order desc limit 21 offset`

Answer (score 1):

From 3.7s to 0.1s over 1.300.000 rows, with these steps:

- Added index on `products.locale`, `products.rating`, `products.reviews` and `products.price`
- Added index on `locations.place_id` and `locations.city_place_id`

The magic happened.